What is the Jewish perspective of natural sciences?
Throughout the centuries Jews have undoubtedly contributed to natural sciences, but I don't really know what the Jewish perspective on natural sciences is, do Jews believe that G-d works through natural science or do they believe that there is a conflict between the Jewish faith and natural sciences?

What do you mean by "natural sciences"?

What do you mean by "G-d works through natural science"?

@DoubleAA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_science.

"Science" is a human endeavor to understand nature. Thus, asking whether God works though it seems to not make sense. That's probably the root of @DoubleAA's concerns.

@IsaacMoses Kabbalistic sources discuss Hashem's involvement in the world through nature which is merumaz in the gematria-similarity of א-להים and הטבע. Analysis of that concept is likely what OP is referring to.

You are asking about Natural Science, and I am presuming you mean the laws of nature (i.e. that which natural science sets out to study). Regarding this, the Jewish perspective is that Hashem runs the world through Hashgacha. This means providence.
Rambam says:

We believe that this Universe remains perpetually with the same
properties with which the Creator has endowed it, and that none of
these will ever be changed except by way of miracle in some individual
instances, although the Creator has the power to change the whole
Universe, to annihilate it, or to remove any of its properties.

There are rather subtle differences among our scholars about what miracles are (e.g.), but generally everyone holds that Hashem is the Master of Nature, having created it and given it all of its power and design, according to His Will. Nevertheless, He likes nature (Derashot HaRan 8:63a) and sticks to the rules of it, out of His own desire, and we can effectively count on that, and therefore His involvement with us is, in a sense, "through nature". Therefore to answer your question specifically:

God indeed involves Himself with the laws of nature, and to a large degree works through them, but we must acknowledge that He is their Master, not the other way around.
There is no conflict between Torah and natural science in principle. Sometimes there is in practice, but that's going to have to come down to superficial differences, such as when science gets something wrong, or we misunderstand Torah, not fundamental ones, such as "Torah doesn't believe in gravity, but science does, so they are at odds".


Natural science (חכמת הטבע) and G-dly wisdom (חכמת אלקות), which includes the subject of Divine Providence (השגחה פרטית), are all rungs on the ladder connecting Heaven and Earth, the ladder of Yaacov Avinu's dream. One doesn't contradict the other and neither can be truly comprehended without knowledge of the other. The Torah of Truth (תורת האמת) means actual reality in every sense.

@YaacovDeane hoping you can comment on the recent question by wmasse about "becoming one with the Ein Sof". Also, there's one on Hashem making the world with letters - your forté

Do you have a link? I'm not finding  it.

It's been closed.

Ramban differentiates between the Mosaic miracles—which worked outside of nature (which he terms 'explicit miracles')—vs providential reward & punishment—which operate within the bounds of nature (which he refers to as 'hidden miracles').
See Ramban, e.g., to Bereishis 17:1

The reason for mentioning this Divine Name now is that with it are done the hidden miracles for the righteous, to deliver their soul from death, and to keep them alive in famine,⁠ as well as to redeem them in war from the power of the sword,⁠ just as all the miracles done to Abraham and to the other patriarchs, and as all the blessings and curses mentioned in the Torah in the section Im Bechukothai and in the section Vehaya Ki Thavo.⁠ These blessings and curses are all miracles for it is not in nature that the rains should come in their due season when we worship G-d, nor are the skies to be like iron if we plant our fields in the seventh year, and similarly all promises in the Torah. Rather, they are all miracles by which the disposition of natural law is overpowered, except that no change from the natural order of the world is noticeable, as was the case with the miracles done through Mosheh Rabbeinu with the ten plagues, the dividing of the Sea, the Manna, the well, and their like, for these are miracles which openly changed nature, and they were done with the Tetragrammaton which He told to him. It is for this reason that He now told Abraham our father that He is the Almighty, the Victor Who will prevail over his constellation of birth so that he will have a son, and thus there will be a covenant between Him and his seed forever, meaning that the portion of the Eternal is His people,⁠ and that He will lead them at His own will, as they will not be under the rule of a star or constellation.

(See What does Ramban refer to with the term "hidden miracles"? for more from Ramban in this regard)
